# how to prevent uimenu (MATLAB) from disappearing when checked

Tags: matlab, checkbox

I have added `uicontextmenu` to the line object. `uicontextmenu` includes 3 check boxes. whenever I check any of them `uicontextmenu` disappears. I want `uicontextmenu` visible for sometime so that i can check multiple boxes and see the change (same as a button group but in `uicontextmenu`). Is there any solution to this or some other approach?

```
cmenu=uicontextmenu;
set(he,'uicontextmenu',cmenu);
item1=uimenu(cmenu,'label','Data A','checked','off','callback',@func_a);
item2=uimenu(cmenu,'label','Data B','checked','off','callback',@func_b);
item3=uimenu(cmenu,'label','Data C','checked','off','callback',@func_c);
```

basically, `he` is the line object created by `plot(x,y)` and `func_a, func_b, func_c` are function to convert property `'checked'` to `on|off`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is greatly inspired by Benoit_11 solution, but a bit refined. I was also under the impression that the 3 different functions in your callback were doing different things so I made the 3 different menus change different properties of the line (instead of changing the same property with different values).

I made the uimenu callback in one single nested function. It decides what to do based on the parameter `what2do` supplied at the uimenu definition (but feel free to keep 3 separate functions). However, note that the function that toggle the check mark is the same for all uimenu (you don't need a separate function for each of them).

```
function hf = TestUiContext2

%// Extension of Benoit_11 solution
clear ; clc ; close all

hf = figure ;               %// return the handle of the figure
hax = axes;                 %// Create axes and save handle
plot(rand(20,3));           %// Plot three lines
hcmenu = uicontextmenu;     %// Define a context menu; it is not attached to anything

%// Define the context menu items and install their callbacks
item1 = uimenu(hcmenu, 'Label','Bold line'   , 'Callback' , {@uiCallback,'bold'} );
item2 = uimenu(hcmenu, 'Label','Dotted line' , 'Callback' , {@uiCallback,'dots'} );
item3 = uimenu(hcmenu, 'Label','Markers on'  , 'Callback' , {@uiCallback,'mark'} );

hlines = findall(hax,'Type','line');        %// Locate line objects
for line = 1:length(hlines)                 %// Attach the context menu to each line
    set(hlines(line),'uicontextmenu',hcmenu)
end

    function uiCallback(obj,~,what2do)
        hline = gco ;
        switch what2do
            case 'bold'
                toggle_bold_line(hline)
            case 'dots'
                toggle_dotted_line(hline)
            case 'mark'
                toggle_markers(hline)
        end
        %// reposition the context menu and make it visible
        set(hcmenu,'Position',get(gcf,'CurrentPoint'),'Visible','on')
        toggle_checkmark(obj)               %// toggle the checkmark
    end

    function toggle_checkmark(obj)
        if strcmp(get(obj,'Checked'),'on')
            set(obj,'Checked','off')
        else
            set(obj,'Checked','on')
        end
    end
    function toggle_bold_line(hline)
        if get(hline,'LineWidth')==0.5
            set(hline,'LineWidth',2)
        else
            set(hline,'LineWidth',0.5)
        end        
    end
    function toggle_dotted_line(hline)
        if strcmpi(get(hline,'LineStyle'),':')
            set(hline,'LineStyle','-')
        else
            set(hline,'LineStyle',':')
        end        
    end
    function toggle_markers(hline)
        if strcmpi(get(hline,'Marker'),'none')
            set(hline,'Marker','o')
        else
            set(hline,'Marker','none')
        end        
    end

end
```

Now you can enjoy ticking all your menu in one go ;)
[image: uicontextexample]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround which might do the trick for you. That's not too elegant but it seems to work.

The trick is to set the menu '`Visible`' property to '`on`' in every callback you have (i.e. @func_a, @funct_b and @funct_c). When I run the following example (based on the demo on the Mathworks website) the menu does not disappear when the selection is changed. Notice that I created separate functions for each callback.

Here is the code:

```
function TestUiContext( ~)

%// Based on example from The Mathworks
%// http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontextmenu.html
clear
clc
close all

%// Create axes and save handle
hax = axes;
%// Plot three lines
plot(rand(20,3));

%// Define a context menu.
hcmenu = uicontextmenu;

%// Define the context menu items and install their callbacks
item1 = uimenu(hcmenu,'Label','dashed','Callback',@(s,e) hcb1);
item2 = uimenu(hcmenu,'Label','dotted','Callback',@(s,e) hcb2);
item3 = uimenu(hcmenu,'Label','solid','Callback',@(s,e) hcb3);
%// Locate line objects
hlines = findall(hax,'Type','line');
%// Attach the context menu to each line
for line = 1:length(hlines)
    set(hlines(line),'uicontextmenu',hcmenu)
end

%// In the callback of every item/option, set the menu property 'Visible' to 'on'.
    function hcb1

        set(gco,'LineStyle','--');        
        set(hcmenu,'Visible','on')
    end

    function hcb2

        set(gco,'LineStyle',':');
        set(hcmenu,'Visible','on')
    end

    function hcb3
        set(gco,'LineStyle','-');
        set(hcmenu,'Visible','on')
    end
end
```

And 2 screenshots to show what it looks like:

[image]

And moving the cursor down:

[image]

So as I said, not perfect but hopefully it will do the job for you!

Comment: Nice one, and you could also reposition the menu as well as making it visible : `set(hcmenu,'Position',get(gcf,'CurrentPoint'),'Visible','on')` so it appear at the same position ;)

Comment: Yeah I thought of that @Hoki, but I was using get(0,'PointerLocation') and it was not working so I gave up and went to bed haha :). Nice solution on your side +1!

Comment: It could work, but with a detour. `get(0,'PointerLocation')` return the position "on the screen". You would then have to translate that to the figure coordinates.